# Kneading and rolling fondant icing without air bubbles

Tags: icing, kneading, rolling

I recently did a short cake decoration course and we rolled out fondant to prepare cake boards and then cover the cakes with fondant. The work surface there was absolutely clean with no scratches and when I kneaded and rolled out fondant, there were no air pockets or bubbles formed.

I then started making cakes at home and the kitchen bench here is not without scratches or bumps. So, I ended up buying a cake mat (plastic sheet) and every single time, there have been air bubbles in the fondant, which I had to remove using a toothpick. But it still leaves a mark on the icing once it goes on the cake.

The question is whether rolling the icing on the plastic cake mat can cause the air bubbles or am I doing something wrong when kneading the fondant? I am using the same store bought fondant as the one we used in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://cakecentral.com/t/711565/why-why-why-do-i-always-have-air-bubbles-in-my-fondant) after researching a bit and tried the recommended method for kneading. According to it, too much folding while kneading causes air bubbles. So, to keep the air bubbles at a minimum, push out with the heel of hand. Stand stretched fondant up on it's side, push down, turn and repeat. I tried to fold as little as possible and instead of getting 6-7 air bubbles, only got 1.

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely (in my opinion) that the air (and subsequently air bubbles) is being introduced into your fondant at the kneading process rather than anything to do with your rolling method or surface used to roll on.

Perhaps experiment a little on a more gentle but firm (as opposed to vigorous) kneading method and see if that removes those air bubbles in your fondant.

Are you kneading the fondant in the same way as instructed on the course?

Comment: Yes, I am kneading it exactly in the same way. The only difference is that I knead it on the plastic cake mat and there are air bubbles under the mat (between the mat and the glass dining table). But I don't know if that has any consequence on it.

Comment: @Divi Then all I can suggest is that you experiment with different kneading techniques and rolling on different surfaces until you can determine what's causing the air bubbles to form in the fondant.